# Comparing an array of time with a time in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of time that I get from the database and pass it to the javascript.when I alert the array variable I get the array of times(in my case 2 different times say 12:00 and 14:30),let the array be `newdate`.
In the javascript I also take in the another time say `date=`(12:00) I want to compare both the timings.both the values in `newdate` compare with `date`.
How to do it?
I tried the following

```
var newdate = new Array();
newdate = $('#newdate').val();
for(i=0;i<newdate.length;i++) {
    alert(newdate[i]);
}

if (newdate >= date) {
    alert("enable");
}
else {
    alert("disbale");
}
```

when I ALERT the above I get 1,2,:,0,0 which is wrong,I want 12:00

Comment: just split with `:` and compare otherwise compare whole value. no need  of `for` loop

Comment: i didnt get you?I am new to javascript

Comment: You're comparing every single character of time string?

Comment: Is your value having only time? like `12:00`

Comment: yup `12:00:00`.this is what I get from the database and pass it to the javascript

Comment: @Vidic it is only one value at a time or is it `,` separated values?

Comment: seperated by commas...12:00:00, 14:30:00

Comment: What's the use for: `var newdate = new Array(); newdate = $('#newdate').val();`? You're overriding the newly created array with a string read from an HTML element.

Comment: @Teemu I pass the db value in a hidden textfield with id=newdate.

Comment: @Satpal wats dat for?

Comment: @Vidic Please re-read my comment above...

Comment: but when I alert newdate I get both the times.So i guess I am right?dont u think?

Comment: @Vidic You have to create an array from your string: `var newdate = $('#newdate').val().split(',');`. Though fixing this leads to the second problem, comparing a quantity of an array is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Consider the following samples :

```
var string = '12:30';
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    console.log(string[i]); // will print each character separately
}
```

```js
var array = ['12:30']; // array of strings
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]); // will print "12:30"
}
```

In the first case, replacing `'12:30'` with `['1', '2', ':', '3', '0']` will give the same result, in other words, looping through a string is like looping through an array of characters. Knowing that, let's return back to your own code :

```
// newdate is an empty array -> []
var newdate = new Array();
// ... then newdate is overwritten with a string -> "12:00"
newdate = $('#newdate').val();
// ... then newdate is traversed -> ["1", "2", ":", "0", "0"]
```

### Solution

Here is how you could test a time against a collection :

```
var temp, item, gte;
var time = '12:15';
var collection = ['12:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '13:00', '11:00'];
var temp = time.split(':');

for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    item = collection[i].split(':');
    gte = +temp[0] >= +item[0];
    if (gte) gte = +temp[1] >= +item[1];
    // if (gte) gte = +temp[2] >= +item[2]; // uncomment to check seconds
    if (gte) alert(time + ' >= item #' + i);
}
```

The above code will alert three times :

```
12:15 >= item #1
12:15 >= item #2
12:15 >= item #5
```

### Going further

Reduces the collection to times that pass the function's test :

```
function filter(collection, fn) {
    var i = 0,
        l = collection.length,
        result = [],
        item;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        item = collection[i];
        if (fn(item, i)) result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Returns a test function for times greater than or equal to the passed one :

```
function gte(time) {
    time = time.split(':');
    return function (item) {
        item = item.split(':');
        return +time[0] < +item[0] || (
            +time[0] === +item[0] && +time[1] <= +item[1]
        );
    };
}
```

Returns a test function for times lower than or equal to the passed one :

```
function lte(time) {
    time = time.split(':');
    return function (item) {
        item = item.split(':');
        return +time[0] >= +item[0] && +time[1] >= +item[1];
    };
}
```

Usage examples :

```
var collection = ['12:45', '12:00', '12:15', '12:30', '13:00', '11:00'];
var gteNoon = filter(collection, gte('12:00'));
var lteNoon = filter(collection, lte('12:00'));
var aroundNoon = filter(collection, function (time) {
    return time.slice(0, 2) === '12';
});

gteNoon;    // ["12:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "13:00"]
lteNoon;    // ["12:00", "11:00"]
aroundNoon; // ["12:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30"]
```

Comment: overwritten with a `time` 12:00:00 and 14:30:00 not string

Comment: @Vidic jQuery `.val()` returns either a string, a number or an array. But more importantly, there is no `time` type in javascript. I've updated the answer with a working sample.

Comment: @Vidic You can trust me :) Indeed, the fact that `newdate` is a string is obvious since your loop alerts one character after the other, this is how a string behaves :)